# Adding a JSON blob to a JSON request in iOS

Tags: ios, json

I need to be able to create a JSON object (I'm using the built in classes in iOS 5).
The JSON that should be sent is this:

```
 {"request_type":"<the request type (a string)>" "security_level":<the security level (an int)> "device_type":"<android or ios (a string)" "version":<the app version (android, ios on different version schemes) (a float)> "email":<the email address of the user sending the request (a string)> "blob":{<the contents of the actual request, encrypted/encoded according to the security level (a map)>}
```

My problem is with the last portion, a "blob"
Which is basically just another JSON object, i.e.

```
 {"display_name":"Jack Bower", "email":"jackb@gmail.com", "password":"roflcopter"}
```

(Let's forget the password is in plaintext)

I can create everything using NSDictionary,
I just don't know how to add the last part.

My guess is create the first request using NSDictionary.
Then create the second blob request using another NSDictionary.
And then just add that second blob NSDictionary as a object back to the initial NSDictionary.

Will NSJSONSerialization understand what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think it's 5am and I'm just being really stupid:

here's the answer:

```
NSDictionary *blobData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             @"email",userEmail,
                             @"password",userPassword,
                      nil];
NSString *blobString = [[NSString alloc]
                        initWithData:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:blobData options:kNilOptions error:&error]
                        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *requestData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             @"login",@"request_type",
                             0,@"security_level",
                             @"ios",@"device_type",
                             @"blob",blobString,
                             nil];
NSData *JSONRequestData = NULL;
if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:requestData]) {
        NSData *JSONRequestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
}
else NSLog(@"requestData was not a proper JSON object");
```